# Escape comma in CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to add an ability to allow users of a wvb app to bulk upload data using a CSV file - everything works great except when the data includes a comma in the actual field itself.

There are lots of posts regarding this and I have read many ways of addressing it mainly by enclosing the comma in double quotes but I cannot figure out how to do this for my code.

Ultimately I cannot rely on users to do this for me at input time so I need to do it as part of the upload process before it hits the database - I tried using tab as an alternate separator but Excel seems to be very inconsistent in how it handles tab separation so I ruled that out.

(sanitiseData is a function I use throughout the site to clean all user input data)

```
        $handle = fopen($file_path, 'r');  
        $row_count=0;

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',')) !== FALSE) {  
            if ($row_count==0) { 
                $row_count++;
                } else {
                    $row_count++;
                    $works_id = sanitiseData($data[0]);
                    $title = sanitiseData($data[1]);
                    $first_name = sanitiseData($data[2]);

                    //Use data to insert into db  
                    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO csv_employee_personal (id,works_id,title,first_name) VALUES ('','$works_id','$title','$first_name')");
                }
        }  

        //delete csv file  
        unlink($file_path);
```

Comment: how are you creating the CSV file?

Comment: Use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) etc. **NOT** `mysql_...`.

Comment: If you have *comma separated values* which contain unescaped commas, the data is invalid. Any attempt to parse it is a lucky guess at best. Require your users to submit **valid** data.

Comment: The file is manually created by the users - I cannot force them to do anything hence why I need to try and prevent it. My current thinking is to tell users they cannot use commas and then as a fallback remove all commas and simply replace with a space?

Comment: not possible till you enclose the fields in double quotes like "123","Mr,Bob"

Comment: How do I enclose them? Where do I do this in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming this is what your data looks like
"data","data2","data3,and some more","data4"

my regex is very bad , but I would think it would be your best solution.

in the mean time you can recursively go trough each character on a line and keep track of commas and field delimiters and when you realize that you are looking at a comma that was not followed by a closing " then you can escape it.

If the example data I gave u matches your data, give me a few mins while I write a function for you to escape commas

Comment: Simplistically the data looks like 123,Mr,Bob when it is given to the application - the issue is if the above comes as 123,Mr,B,ob

Comment: oh, sorry sir, not sure how you can differentiate the comma in bob's name and a real comma separating the fields.

Comment: its probably bad advice, but will the extra comma always be in the name? if first column is always id, and second column is a 2-3 letter title abriviation, then you can prob do a string replace past that point

Comment: Unfortunately not - there shouldn't be any commas but I need to protect against someone accidentally or deliberately uploading a csv with a comma in one of the fields

Comment: then check to see if there is more than 3 commas on that line , keep note of it dont insert and move onto next line, at the end of the script prompt the user with the mistaken line in a textbox for them to fix there issue and submit the new changes of the broken line